# Updating expiring secret for credential using Azure app registration and the SQL Server Connector breaks TDE

Tags: sql-server, transparent-data-encryption

About 2 years ago we implemented TDE on several databases. We are using the SQL Server Connector for the Azure Key Vault and have a credential in SQL Server that authenticates using the application registration we created in Azure. The secret is expiring and I thought it would be as simple as creating a new secret and updating the secret value for the credential. However when I do that it immediately puts all databases in recovery pending and I get a message in event viewer saying "the request is invalid" and in the SQL Server Logs "provider error code: 3110" and "no explanation is available."

I cannot finding any supporting documentation on this. I'm hoping I do not have to fully decrypt and re-encrypt for a simple secret update? Any advice is appreciated.

Generated a new secret, ran an alter credential statement in SQL Server with the new appid/secret combo for the secret value and restarted SQL Server. Expected operations to continue normally but instead all databases went into recovery pending.

Comment: It's unclear which secret you're changing, the secret stored in Key Vault or the Client Secret for your App Registration used to access Key Vault.

Comment: I am trying to update the app registration secret. However as I have continued to try things including generating a new asymmetric key, I've found that whatever is happening is not unique to updating the secret but rather some issue with the connector communicating with Azure. I get: Operation: acquireToken Key Name: Message: [error:110, info:400, state:0] The request is invalid. This usually means the key name is invalid or contains invalid characters. However the key name meets all requirements. I get that message even just updating the secret.